# I need to compare 2 nested lists in python to find where a string of the first list does not match with the string in the second list

Tags: python, nested-lists, unification, first-order-logic

If I have these 2 lists:

```
list1 = ['P', ['f', 'X', 'a'], ['g', 'Y', ['f', 'a']]]
list2 = ['P', ['f', ['f', 'a'], 'a'], ['g', 'X', ['f', 'X']]]
```

In these 2 lists, in the first nested list we have ['f', 'X', 'a'] and ['f', ['f', 'a'], 'a'] respectively for list1 and list2.
I need to find these situations and replace the unmatched strings (or lists). For example, in this 2 sublists I need to replace ['f', 'a'] with 'X', so that at the end, both lists are the same. (This is for First-Order logic unification).

So far I have the following code to pair my lists but I don't know where to go from there:

```
list1 = ['P', ['f', 'X', 'a'], ['g', 'Y', ['f', 'a']]]
list2 = ['P', ['f', ['f', 'a'], 'a'], ['g', 'X', ['f', 'X']]]


temp = len(list1) * '% s = %% s, '
res = temp % tuple(list1) % tuple(list2)
print("The paired elements string is : " + res)
```

Where I get the following output:

```
P = P, ['f', 'X', 'a'] = ['f', ['f', 'a'], 'a'], ['g', 'Y', ['f', 'a']] = ['g', 'X', ['f', 'X']]
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. I'm very new to python.

Comment: list1 = ['P', ['f', 'X', 'a'], ['g', 'Y', ['f', 'a']]]

Comment: is comparison case-sensitive?

Comment: @AryanMishra yes it is

Answer (score 0):

```
list2 = ['P', ['f', ['f', 'a'], 'a'], ['g', 'X', ['f', 'X']]]

def repList(mlist):
    rlist = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(mlist):
        f = False
        if i < len(mlist) - 2 and type (mlist[i]) == str and type(mlist[i+1]) == list and type (mlist[i + 2]) == str:
            sublist = mlist[i + 1]
            if len(sublist) == 2 and mlist[i] == sublist[0] and mlist[i + 2] == sublist[1]:
                f = True
        if f : 
            rlist.append(mlist[i])
            rlist.append('X')
            rlist.append(mlist[i+2])
            i += 2
         elif type(mlist[i]) == list:
            rlist.append(repList(mlist[i]))
         else: 
            rlist.append(mlist[i])
         i+=1

return rlist

list3 = repList(list2)
print (list3)
```